# Webform composite sub-element altering : how to do?

Tags: webforms, 9

I'm currently developing a Webform based module (D9). One functionality I'm working on is around form "interdependency" : for a given form, some fields can be pre-filled from another webform submission of the same user. The hard part is tat I want to prevent end-user editing the prefilled data; I'm think about / testing multiples options :

1. Simply add `#disabled` property to each prefilled fields : not good because `disabled` field values are NOT submitted
2. Simply add `#readonly` property to each prefilled fields : not good because some field cannot be "readonly" such as select (and `readonly` attribute can be easily removed by end-user)
3. Do not "write protect" pre-filled fields, but override all prefilled fields juste before entity saving (entity presave maybe ?) with initial data values
4. Alter each-prefilled field to transform them to textfield, or markup + hidden field

For about all those options I need to be able to *alter* the custom composite fields, and theirs values (multivalues custom composite field). For now, I'm able to loop over the custom composite structure (`$form['elements']['my_composite_field']['#element']['my_composite_subfield']`) in classic `hook_form_alter` ; but I don't know how to *alter* `my_composite_subfield` fields individually (because pre-filled fields must be altered, unlike any *new item* added by user (native "add more item" ajax button).

Can you please help ? Which hook can be used ? Or maybe a Webform custom handler ?

Thanks